# is there a function that can prove if a matrix is square using the base functions?

Tags: r, matrix

#Complete the code chunk in the template to write a function that accepts a matrix (of any size) M as an argument and returns TRUE if the matrix is square and FALSE otherwise. It should work for scalars as well.

#I am given the first part of the code:

````
```{r}
````

is.square <- function(M) {

}

```
#and I am required to finish the code so that it gives "TRUE" OR "FALSE" when I test the code on these examples: 

#a=2
# is.square(a)
#
# A = matrix(1:4,nrow=2,ncol=2) # is.square(A)
#
# B = matrix(1:9,nrow=3,ncol=3) # is.square(B)
#
# C = matrix(1:6,nrow=3,ncol=2) # is.square(C)


#only base functions are allowed and no matter what I try I cannot get it right. 

#I've tried 

    is.square <- function(M) {
  
  if(dim(M)[1]) != dim(M)[2]) {
    
    return(FALSE)
    
  } else {
    
    return(TRUE)
  }

}


#but get the errors 
> is.square <- function(M) {
+   
+   if(dim(M)[1]) != dim(M)[2]) {
Error: unexpected '!=' in:
"  
  if(dim(M)[1]) !="
>     
>     return(FALSE)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
>     
>   } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>     
>     return(TRUE)
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
>   }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> 
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to do your homework *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve problems you encounter whilst *doing it for yourself*. "You must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself. The question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." For more detail, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822).

Comment: *"no matter what I try I cannot get it right"*. What have you tried? Show us! Do you have an idea for how you would like to solve it? Tell us!

Comment: A clue is that `dim(M)` will give you a two-element vector with the number of rows and number of columns. Remember you can subset this vector using `dim(M)[1]` to get the number of rows, and `dim(M)[2]` to get the number of columns. Also remember you can test for equality using `==`

Comment: @GregorThomas I've edited it to now show what I have tried and the errors I get back

Comment: @Limey I am new to using R Studio and new to using this kind of platform to ask for help. I did not know that I needed to show what I have tried already but I have since updated the post. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think you had a typo in the line

```
(dim(M)[1]) != dim(M)[2])
```

which is supposed to be

```
(dim(M)[1] != dim(M)[2])
```

Comment: this code works except for a=2 when trying is.square(a). Does this mean I leave the code as is and leave the error since the code works for the rest of the data I need to test?

Comment: @kay You can use `M <- t(M)` as your first line in your function body and try again.